# Как пользоваться базой данных на heroku

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord, sequelize.js

У меня есть дискорд бот, написанный на js. Я его выгрузил на heroku все работает. Мой бот использует базу данных, которую редактирует в ходе использования. Я пробовал выгружать бота с базой на heroku (очевидно глупая идея), после перезагрузки бота (что снова очевидно) данные сбрасывались. Я читал про миграции бд, но не думаю, что этот вариант мне подходит, ибо хочу полную независимость моего бота от моего пк, да и не совсем понимаю как это реализовать. Пользуюсь sequelize, диалект sqlite, подскажите пожалуйста практичное и простое решение
Вот структура бд:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    // SQLite only
    storage: 'database_production.sqlite',
});

const database = sequelize.define('base', {
    guild_id: Sequelize.STRING,
    user_id: Sequelize.STRING,
    balance: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В качестве альтернативы, если вам не критична реляционность и скорость вашего хранилища данных. Попробуйте организовать онлайн хранилище с помощью **MongoDB Atlas** это решение предлагает бесплатные тарифы для кластеров с максимальным объемом до 5Gb данных.

MongoDB использует JSON подобную схему для хранения данных, поэтому с опытом работы с JavaScript объектами вы легко и быстро освоите её.